# How to solve "undeclared identifier" and "redefinition of formal parameter"?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I'm working on a programme to calculate average acceleration and i use 3 function ( by pass reference method) after writing my code this error happens 
and "error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'Vo'".I've google it and i barely understand it.Can anyone explain to me why this happens and how to solve this?thank you for helping

```
/* lab assessment 4 kiraan pecutan*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void data(double& Vo,double& Vt,double& t);
void calculate(double& sum);
void output(double& out);
double Vo,Vt,t,sum,out;
int main()
{

cout<<"please enter your velocity(Vo=m/s)\n,velocity(Vt=m/s)\nand time(s=second)\n\n";

data(Vo,Vt,t);

calculate(sum);

output( out);
return 0;
}

void data(double& Vo,double& Vt,double& t)
{
    double Vo,Vt,t;
    cin>>Vo;
    cin>>Vt;
    cin>>t;
    cout<<"your Vo="<<Vo<<" ,Vt="<<Vt<<" and T="<<t<<"\n\n";
}

void calculate(double& sum )
{
    double Vt,Vo,t;
    sum=(Vt-Vo)/t;
}

void output(double& out)
{
    double sum;
  cout<<"the acceleration ="<<sum;
}
```

Comment: "C2065: 'accel' : undeclared identifier" - there is no `accel` identifier in the code you've posted, so obviously you haven't shown us the code that's actually causing the problem. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You declare variables with the same name multiple times. Each variable defined by its name should be declared exactly ones. It is not allowed to use the same variable name e.g. as a function parameter and a variable name in the function body, e.g.

```
void data(double &Vo) {
  double Vo = 0.0;   // Vo already exists with type double&
  // do something
}
```

---

Please consider the following hints:

- do not use global variables unless necessary, they are hard to debug in big   projects
- always initialize variables of basic types (int, float, double, ...) with a value otherwise they get a 'random' one

The following code should compile without errors, even though the semantic/computation maybe wrong. I just used your implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
using namesace std;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void data(double &Vo, double &Vt, double &t);
void calculate(double &Vo, double &Vt, double &t, double &sum);
void output(double &out);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int main() {
  double Vo = 0.0;
  double Vt = 0.0;
  double t = 0.0;
  double sum = 0.0;
  double out = 0.0;

  cout << "please enter your velocity(Vo=m/s)\n,velocity(Vt=m/s)\nand time(s=second)\n\n";
  data(Vo, Vt, t);
  calculate(Vo, Vt, t, sum);
  output(out);
  return 0;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void data(double &Vo, double &Vt, double &t) {
  cin >> Vo;
  cin >> Vt;
  cin >> t;
  cout << "your Vo=" << Vo << " ,Vt=" << Vt << " and T=" << t << "\n\n";
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void calculate(double &Vo, double &Vt, double &t, double &sum) {
  sum = (Vt - Vo) / t;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void output(double &out) {
  cout << "the acceleration =" << out;
}
```